# Float doesn't change when i add 0.1 to it

Tags: c

I am quite a newbie to c. So when i writing a small game demo, i face a really strange problem.

```
 void testC()
 {
     float a = 825300160;
     float b = a + 0.1;
     assert(a != b);
 }
```

The above assert statement can't passed. Very strange.
My environment is mac os ml. gcc 4.2.1

Comment: `float` doesn't have enough precision to distinguish between `825300160` and `825300160.1`.

Comment: A float number has about 6 decimal digits of precision.  (Try `double` instead.)

Comment: `float` usually has a precision of only 24 bits. `a` is larger than `2^29`, and `b < 2^(-3)`, so `b` is several bits beyond what could influence `a`.

Comment: I forgot it, how stupid i am.

Comment: Google for *"What every programmer should know about floating point arithmetic"*.

Comment: Not "stupid" -- it's something you kinda have to learn by tripping over it a few times.  In a classroom the concept has no meaning, but when you get burned by it a few times you develop a intuitive feel for when you might have a problem with this.  (Better in a simple program than on a Mars mission.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The fractional portion of a `float` consists of 23 bits. You need 30 bits to represent 825300160, so the less significant portion of the number is dropped. Adding `.1` does not make a difference - you need to add roughly `32` for the number to change:

```
float a = 825300160;
float b = a + 31.5;
assert(a != b); // No change is detected
float c = a + 32;
assert(a != c); // Change is detected
```

Comment: +1 For an awesome explanation of floating point. I wish I knew the floating point standard this well.

Comment: So can i do something to my compiler to avoid this problem happens a bit. I mean if the compiler give a warning when i do the same thing again. Or should i just keep in mind the range of float and won't let it happen again. Thanks.

Comment: Because i am a java programmer before, the compiler won't let me compile, even if any tiny problem hided in my code. So when i write c code, i will face a lot of problems i haven't even thought before.

Comment: @user674199 Unfortunately, the compiler does not warn you on something like that: the `825300160` is within the representable range of a `float`, just the precision is not there to support "small" increments. Unlike Java and C#, C compiler trusts programmers a lot more, even when their actions may look suspicious.

Answer (score 6):

There's not enough precision in the float type. If you really need to distinguish a 0.1 addition to a number as large as 825300160, use double.

Answer (score 1):

As [this site](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) shows, both a and b would be represented as

```
0 10011100 10001001100010001010011
```

in the IEEE standard for floats, where the first bit is the sign, the next 8 are the exponent, and the remaining 23 the mantissa.  There's just not enough space in those 23 bits to represent the difference, because the exponent is so large.